# Alternative for namespace "System.Environment"?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hi all i made a program in VB.NET and i used System.Environment namespace witch found in 4.5 where i found an alternative for that namespace ? i using namespace to "(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)" 
Thanks !

Comment: This question is unrelated to VBScript, so I removed the respective tag.

Comment: Can you try to describe the actual problem you are facing? I think that might help you get the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, `Environment` is a class in the `System` namespace.  It's not, itself, a namespace.  The [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) method has been around since version 1.1 of the framework, so you shouldn't need an alternative unless you are targeting all the way back to the 1.0 framework.  If that is the case, I suspect an API call will be your best option.  If so, look into the [SHGetFolderPath](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetFolderPath.html) function.